# How to copy certain similar rows of data from excel file and save into another excel file?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsx

I would like to ask how to copy certain similar rows of data from an excel file and save into another excel file according to specific column name? I would like to find out the similar word according to column no1 which is 'name' (there is 3 columns in the input file which is name, number and number), then copy the whole row into another excel file. Next, I also want the amount of row is the same by adding 'zzzz | 0 | 0 ' on the missing row.

Eventually, there will be 3 different excel files. All has same amount of row, for this case, each of the files have 4 rows.

input (excel file):

```
name | number | number 
aaaa | 123456 | 223456
aaaa | 123456 | 221456
bbbb | 123356 | 228456
bbbb | 123556 | 229456
cccc | 123756 | 200456
cccc | 122256 | 220756
cccc | 121156 | 226656
```

expected output (excel file no1):

```
name | number | number 
aaaa | 123456 | 223456
aaaa | 123456 | 221456
zzzz | 0      | 0
```

expected output (excel file no2):

```
name | number | number 
bbbb | 123356 | 228456
bbbb | 123556 | 229456
zzzz | 0      | 0
```

expected output (excel file no3):

```
name | number | number 
cccc | 123756 | 200456
cccc | 122256 | 220756
cccc | 121156 | 226656
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You can read the excel into DataFrame and apply the logic and save the DataFrame back to excel.

Comment: Hi @nag, sorry that I am newbie of python, may I know how to apply the logic? It is even better if you don't mind to share your codes, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check with `goupby` + `reindex`

```
g=df.groupby('name')
for x , y in g : 

    y=y.reset_index(drop=True).reindex(range(g.size().max())).fillna({'name':'zzzz'}).fillna(0)
    y.to_csv(x+'.csv')
    print(y)

   name    number  number.1
0  aaaa  123456.0  223456.0
1  aaaa  123456.0  221456.0
2  zzzz       0.0       0.0
   name    number  number.1
0  bbbb  123356.0  228456.0
1  bbbb  123556.0  229456.0
2  zzzz       0.0       0.0
   name  number  number.1
0  cccc  123756    200456
1  cccc  122256    220756
2  cccc  121156    226656
```

Comment: Hi @WeNYoBen, thanks for your reply, I almost get answer but just a minor problem which is the first row column 'number', I got 'Unnamed: 1' instead of 'number' and 'Unnamed: 2' instead of 'number.1', may I know any mistake I done? I had added one line code at the front on your codes, here is the code:
 `g = pd.read_excel("file.xlsx")`

Comment: @EdisonToh You can rename you columns by `g.columns=['name','number','number1']`

Comment: Hi @WeNYoBen, sorry for disturbing you, how to add fixed row amount like 5 rows starting from every ['name','number','number1'] row?